# Guaranteeing asynchronous request callback order in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, callback

In Javascript, I have two asychronous requests for data:

```
$.getJSON('http://foo.com', fooQuery, fooSuccess(data));
$.getJSON('http://bar.com', barQuery, barSuccess(data));
```

and two callbacks to process the received data:

```
fooSuccess(data) { // Stuff }
barSuccess(data) { // More Stuff }
```

How do I ensure barSuccess is executed only after fooSuccess completes?

Notes:

- I want to keep the data requests as they are: asynchronous and non-blocking (since server responses may take a while).
- But, I want the callbacks that process the data to be executed sequentially. That is, I do not want to execute barSuccess until fooSuccess completes.

Thanks so much for your wisdom and help!

Comment: You want the [jQuery Promise/Deferred Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

Comment: @JaredFarrish make this an answer!

Comment: Oh yeah, there's also the newish [`jQuery.Callbacks()`](http://api.jquery.com/category/callbacks-object/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how you would do it using the jQuery deferred object that is returned by ajax requests.

```
var fooDfd = $.getJSON('http://foo.com', fooQuery);
var barDfd = $.getJSON('http://bar.com', barQuery);

fooDfd.then(function(fooData){
    fooSuccess(fooData);
    barDfd.then(barSuccess);
});
```

​

Comment: While this would do what the OP is looking to do, it might be better to use a `$.when().done()` construct to make the AJAX calls in parallel.

Comment: This is perfect! So succinct, and does exactly what I want. Thanks so much David.

Comment: @MikeBrant The calls _are_ both done in parallel, they are fired off by the first 2 lines.

Answer (score 5):

The best way would be to utilize the jQuery `when().done()` functionality like this:

```
$.when(
    $.getJSON('http://foo.com', fooQuery, fooSuccess(data)), 
    $.getJSON('http://bar.com', barQuery, barSuccess(data))
).done(function(arg1, arg2){
    fooSuccess(arg1);
    barSuccess(arg2);
});
```

This allow simultaneous execution of the AJAX requests and guaranteed execution of the `done()` function once all requests has successfully completed.

Comment: Thanks so much Mike! I didn't know there were so many different ways to do this with jQuery. If I weren't such a newbie, I would upvote both your response and David's (still below the point threshold to upvote).

Comment: The difference between our two answers is that I allowed the `fooSuccess` handler to run with only the response from `http://foo.com` rather than waiting for bar to complete as well.

Comment: @david Indeed.  I guess the right approach would be to really see which way yields the best overall response time.  I guess I was assuming the ajax calls would be the most time consuming and that  the success handlers would be less time consuming, thus meaning it might be best to make those calls in parallel.  If it is imperative to get `fooSuccess` run at the earliest possible point your approach would be better in all cases where the `foo` AJAX call takes less time than the `bar` AJAX call. So to summarize, the OP should perhaps test both ways and see which makes sense for them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm follow this very interesting post from a half an hour ago, when appear the elegant solution presented by @Mike Brant I quickly was to dive in the jquery library to see how the magic is made. Don't you? I recommend, is very interesting!
BTW I think we don't need all that magic, not in this case, we have two asynchronous calls handlers(functions), no matter which end first, we need to know when the second end, then all we need is a third function that will be called by the two handlers and act when all the data is ready. I know this approach will vaste four or five lines more of code than the elegant jquery solution, but at the end our brain and soul will be in better condition. Sorry my english.

Answer (score -1):

Put the `barSuccess` call in the `fooSuccess` success callback.

```
fooSuccess(data){
  jQuery.ajax({
    data: data,
    success: function(response){
      barSuccess(data) //should still be in scope, I think?
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This will not allow `barSuccess` to access the return value of `barQuery`.

Comment: After update: This chains the AJAX calls, what OP specifically doesn't want. Promises or manual code to that effect is what is needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Colleen, but wouldn't this mean that the request for bar would only happen after the request for foo is completed? If so, this is not what I want. E.g. If foo request and bar request both take 5 seconds to return, I want fooSuccess and barSuccess to complete processing in ~5 seconds rather than ~10 seconds.

Comment: Ah, misunderstood-- I assumed a certain level of sequentialness was ok, as long as the individual requests themselves were asynchronous.

Comment: @ChrisHan, you are looking for jQuery's Deferred utility. It's literally *exactly* what you're describing.